# How to add sound to notification in titanium

Tags: android, audio, notifications, titanium

I'm creating my notification this way:

```
var notification = Titanium.Android.createNotification({
    contentTitle : 'teste #' + nId,
    contentText : 'Click to return to the application.',
    contentIntent : pending,
    sound : Ti.Filesystem.getResRawDirectory() + 'am.mp3',
});
```

Then I call the sound method but I'm unable to get sound on my Android phone. I have put the 'am.mp3' file in resources, resources -> android, have created a folder named resources -> android -> raw, resources -> android -> res -> raw and now solution worked. I have also tried:

```
sound : "/android/res/raw/am.mp3"
```

like I do with images

Does someone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

To create a raw resource, place the audio file in the `platform/android/res/raw` folder and reference it as:

```
notification.sound = Ti.Filesystem.getResRawDirectory() + audioFileName;
```

**Sound**
To play a sound when the notification first appears, assign the Notification object's sound property a sound file to play. Place the file in the `/platform/android/res/raw/` folder. Reference the file by using the `Ti.Filesystem.getResRawDirectory()` method to retrieve the location of the file, then append the filename to the end, for example, `Ti.Filesystem.getResRawDirectory() + 'sound.wav'` .

By default, the sound plays each time the application calls the `notify()` method. To override this behavior, add the `Titanium.Android.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE` constant to the Notification object's flags property.

```
var notification = Titanium.Android.createNotification({
    contentTitle: 'Notification 2',
    contentText : 'Just another notification',
    contentIntent: Ti.Android.createPendingIntent({intent: Ti.Android.createIntent({})}),
    icon: Ti.App.Android.R.drawable.warn,
    number: 5,
    when: new Date().getTime(),
    // Sound file located at /platform/android/res/raw/sound.wav
    sound: Ti.Filesystem.getResRawDirectory() + 'sound.wav',
});
```

Source [1](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Notification-property-sound),[2](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Notifications)

Comment: I have already tried this solution. I have inclusive created the folder res and raw

Comment: @Manuel_Rodrigues make sure your phone is not on silent.

Comment: Im sure of that because i'm receiving notifications from other app's

Comment: @Manuel_Rodrigues try to use another sound tf it works then problem is in am.mp3

Comment: but the am.mp3 file plays in the cumputer